# CSS visual rendering not showing until JS script has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JS function which is triggered on a click event.
At the very first line in the function, I add a class to a html element. The html is a custom loader, and the class just makes the loader visible.

The problem is that the loader does not appear until the script has actually finished executing. The class is set on the element right after the script starts, but nothing visually happens in my browser until the script has finished executing.

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(){ 
    $('#loader').addClass('active');

    $('.fields').each(function(i, el){
       // does some intensive stuff, including appending elements to a dom fragment, triggering events programmatically. This takes 5-10s to execute.
    });

    // the loader only appears visible in the browser once the code executed in the loop finishes.
});
```

The CSS in the active class is:

```
.active{
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    left: calc(50% - 18px);
    left: -webkit-calc(50% - 18px);
    top: 40%;
}
```

I tried do re-search this issue, but I couldn't find anything on google.
Maybe it's because I do not know what keywords I should search, I am not sure what is causing or how to refer to this issue.

So guys, you are my last hope. Could you point me in the right direction on how to debug or what is causing this?

If I add the fields loop inside a `setTimeout` function with 0 timeout, it works. But the idea is to fix it the correct way, and understand why it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

> If I add the fields loop inside a setTimeout function with 0 timeout, it works.

This is a sensible approach, although `requestAnimationFrame` is stylistically slightly nicer.

> But the idea is to fix it the correct way, and understand why it's not working as expected.

The browser won't trigger a repaint until the function has finished running - otherwise, it would do a repaint for every individual DOM modification, which would be expensive.

Comment: or maybe his CSS is underneath the javascript, CSS doesn't load until the scripts compiled fully.

Comment: @GamersAgenda — No. It's a function trigged by a click.

Comment: @Quentin, using requestAnimationFrame seems better. However I couldn't get it work for me, I am not sure why. I did it identically as in their example but it didn't work, the function called with requestAnimationFrame still executed after the block of code finished. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Quentin, I looked more into it, and it seems that requestAnimationFrame does not work with CSS classes, it only works with JS animations. Any other suggestions besides using setTimeout?